# What is a good approach of organising routes in express?

Tags: express

As project began to handle *more then 3 routes*, router files get *messy*.

Besides splitting router file itself, is it ok to separate urls and view functions (like in django)?

For example urls:

```js
//./urls.js

const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const views = require('./views')


router.get('/', views.index)
router.post('/create', views.createItem)
router.get('/:id/delete', views.deleteItem)
router.get('/:id/update', views.updateItem)


module.exports = router
```

that calls view-functions:

```js
//./views.js

exports.index = async (req, res) => {
   ...
}

exports.createItem = async (req, res) => {
   ...
}

exports.updateItem = async (req, res) => {
   ...
}

exports.deleteItem = async (req, res) => {
   ...
}
```

If it's not good, what is your approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separating *routes* and *view functions* is a common practice. In express terminology view functions (or route-handler callback functions) are implemented with *controller* module.

For example

```js
//./controllers/authorController.js

// Display Author create form on GET.
exports.author_create_get = function(req, res) {
    res.send('NOT IMPLEMENTED: Author create GET');
};

// Handle Author create on POST.
exports.author_create_post = function(req, res) {
    res.send('NOT IMPLEMENTED: Author create POST');
};
```

And routes would be something like

```js
//./routes/catalog.js

// Display Author create form on GET.
exports.author_create_get = function(req, res) {
    res.send('NOT IMPLEMENTED: Author create GET');
};

// Handle Author create on POST.
exports.author_create_post = function(req, res) {
    res.send('NOT IMPLEMENTED: Author create POST');
};
```

More on this on developer.mozilla.org: [Express Tutorial Part 4: Routes and controllers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes)